# mysql key column doesnt exist in table

Tags: mysql, sql

```
CREATE TABLE DONOR
(
donor_id int,
medical_history varchar(20),
donor_name varchar(50),
blood_group char(2),
address varchar(80),
contact_number int,
PRIMARY KEY (donor_id)
);

CREATE TABLE RECEPTIONIST
(
recep_id varchar(10),
recep_name varchar(50),
phone_number int,
donor_id int,
PRIMARY KEY (recep_id),
FOREIGN KEY (donor_id) REFERENCES DONOR (donor_id)
);

CREATE TABLE HOSPITAL
(
hospital_id varchar(10),
hospital_name varchar(50),
hospital_address varchar(80),
PRIMARY KEY (hospital_id)
);

CREATE TABLE BLOOD_BANK 
(
blood_bank_id varchar(10),
blood_group char(2),
stocks int,
PRIMARY KEY (blood_bank_id),
FOREIGN KEY (recep_id) REFERENCES RECEPTIONIST (recep_id),
FOREIGN KEY (hospital_id) REFERENCES HOSPITAL (hospital_id)
);

CREATE TABLE BLOOD
(
blood_code varchar(10),
blood_group char(2),
expired_date date,
PRIMARY KEY (blood_code)
);

CREATE TABLE PATIENT
(
patient_id varchar(10),
patient_name varchar(50),
contact_number int,
blood_group char(2),
address varchar(80),
PRIMARY KEY(patient_id),
FOREIGN KEY (hospital_id) REFERENCES HOSPITAL (hospital_id)
);
```

hi, i wrote this for my project in mysql and i dont understand why it said

> Key column 'recep_id' doesn't exist

in table when i want to execute the code

it said that i need to define it in receptionist table but i already defined it

```
CREATE TABLE RECEPTIONIST
(
recep_id varchar(10),
```

the entity relationship between blood bank and receptionist is one receptionist works at a blood bank.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is this line:

```
FOREIGN KEY (recep_id) REFERENCES RECEPTIONIST (recep_id),
```

while creating the table `BLOOD_BANK`.
The table `BLOOD_BANK` does not have the column `recep_id` which you reference in the statement. You ave to add the column to the table `BLOOK_BANK`

```
CREATE TABLE BLOOD_BANK 
(
blood_bank_id varchar(10),
blood_group char(2),
stocks int,
recep_id varchar(10),
hospital_id varchar(10),
PRIMARY KEY (blood_bank_id),
FOREIGN KEY (recep_id) REFERENCES RECEPTIONIST (recep_id),
FOREIGN KEY (hospital_id) REFERENCES HOSPITAL (hospital_id)
);
```

Same for the `hospital_id` in the table `BLOOD_BANK` and `PATIENT`

```
CREATE TABLE PATIENT
(
patient_id varchar(10),
patient_name varchar(50),
contact_number int,
blood_group char(2),
address varchar(80),
hospital_id varchar(10),
PRIMARY KEY(patient_id),
FOREIGN KEY (hospital_id) REFERENCES HOSPITAL (hospital_id)
);
```